# Understanding behavior of django model save

Tags: python, django

When using the shell, this confused me (the permissions did not reflect changes):

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='test')
>>> user.get_all_permissions()
set([])
>>> p = Permission.objects.get(codename="add_slide")
>>> user.user_permissions.add(p)
>>> user.save()
>>> user.get_all_permissions()
set([])
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='test')
>>> user.get_all_permissions()
set([u'slides.add_slide'])
```

Why did the user object not update on save?
Is there a way save and update the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because User has a many2many relationship with Permission, so when you do `user.user_permissions.add(p)`, the "auth_user" table does not get updated. Instead, its the "through" table for that relationship ("auth_user_user_permissions") that gets updated. In fact, you don't need to call `user.save()` at all.

The `get_all_permissions()` method appears to be using cached data, so if you want the latest changes, use:

```
user.user_permissions.all()
```

Note that this will return a list of Permission objects, so if you want a list of codenames in the exact same format as a `get_all_permissions()` call (not sure why you would though), you can do this:

```
set(user.user_permissions.values_list('codename', flat=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't update in-memory objects when on-disk objects change.  Your first user still looks as it does when it was read from disk.

Comment: So that explains what is happening but not really why?  or the best way to update in-memory objects with on-disk changes?

Comment: The example you gave is kind of a special case because the `get_all_permissions()` method, which is a `User` model-specific method, happens to use caching. If you use the more generic Django model methods/properties, you'll find that they behave more intuitively and will update when you would expect them to.